# jQuery.parseJSON returning empty data structure

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I am having a perplexing issue with data manipulation in JavaScript.

I am using the following code in JavaScript to retrieve data from a PHP/MySQL source.

```
var _response = jQuery.ajax({
    url: "../data",
    async: false,
    type: "post",
    data: oParams
}).responseText;
```

and have confirmed that the contents of _response are

```
_response = '{"genus":["Some Data"],"series":[],"program":["Some Data1","Some Data2","Some Data3"]}';
```

However when doing the following:

```
var _return = jQuery.parseJSON( _response );
console.log( _return );
```

I end up with:

```
genus: [""]
program: ["", "", ""]
series: []
```

according to firebug. I have even gone as far as to put the string directly into jQuery.parseJSON() and log the result and still end up with an empty data structure.

Does anyone know what is going on here or what would cause this?

Comment: strange, checked it and it gets parsed correctly for me :( Can you double check you are using the latest jQuery? maybe you have a buggy version?

Comment: No problem, http://jsfiddle.net/wX4D5/, maybe it't the problem of your firebug.

Comment: I have tried both jQuery 1.6.4 and 1.7.1 and gotten the same result in Firefox and Chrome. I don't expect anyone to respond but I posted the full code set in case there is something glaring that I am missing at: http://jsfiddle.net/Gw6FM/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There must be something wrong either with your jQuery file or your browser. It works fine for me in jQuery 1.7.1:

```
> var x = $.parseJSON('{"genus":["Some Data"],"series":[],"program":["Some Data1","Some Data2","Some Data3"]}');
undefined
> x["genus"]
["Some Data"]
```

Comment: I wanted to give you credit since you are indirectly correct. There was a bug in my code, one solitary if() comparison has a single = instead of a == and it was evaporating all my data.